# Python: unit tests in different folder than production code?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've read multiple articles and questions on StackOverflow and was wondering why no one uses the following structure for unit tests in Python:

```
MyProject/
    main/
        module1/
            my_file.py
    test/
        module1/
            test_my_file.py
```

What I've read is that you either:

1. Put `test_my_file.py` in the same directory as `my_file.py`:

   ```
   MyProject/
       module1/
           my_file.py
           test_my_file.py
   ```
2. Put `test_my_file.py` in a directory named `test` in the same directory as `my_file.py`:

   ```
   MyProject/
       module1/
           my_file.py
           test/
               test_my_file.py
   ```

Notes:

1. I come from a Java world: having unit test code at the same place as production code feels weird to me.
2. I'm very new to Python: there's probably some obvious reason I'm missing here. (My first guess would be that it has something to do with modules)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because I also wrote a lot of Java code before coming to Python, but I also keep my tests in a separate folder from production code on most of my Python projects. The only hassle is that sometimes you have to mess around with `PYTHONPATH` or relative imports to help the tests find the production code for importing.

In [this project](https://github.com/donkirkby/live-py-plugin/blob/master/tox.ini), I set the `PYTHONPATH` in my tox configuration.

```
setenv = PYTHONPATH=plugin/PySrc
commands =
     py.test plugin/PySrc/ test/PySrc/ --cov-report term-missing --cov plugin/PySrc/
     coverage xml
```